# Invalid API Credentials

Tags: java, android

I can now connect to my API but somehow it telling me that "Invalid API Creadentials" i do addHeader but it is not passing to api

```
 RequestParams p = new RequestParams();
    p.add("Username","asd");
    p.add("Password","asdqwe");

    SISOB_APIURL = "http://services.lbcexpress.com/sisob/api/Values?";
    client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.addHeader("API_KEY","HESOYAM");
    client.addHeader("API_SECRET","BAGUVIX");
    client.get(this,SISOB_APIURL,p, new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response) {
            super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
            Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
            super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, responseString, throwable);
            Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this, responseString.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is your API credential correctly insterted or not check at once?

Comment: yes i can access my api with my postman

Answer (score 0):

thanks for answering guys my problem is the keyname
now it is working,

```
client.addHeader("APIKEY","HESOYAM");
client.addHeader("APISECRET","BAGUVIX");
```